# Witch Doctor pets, Fierce Loyalty and LOH

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

I am wondering if the LOH of the player is naturally transfered to the Witch Doctor pets (patch 1.0.4). If yes, is there restriction (like a reduced proc or reduced amount), and if not, does Fierce Loyalty only transfer "Life regeneration" bonus or also "Life on hit" and "Life leech" bonuses ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gargantuan has a proc coefficient of 0, which means that no on-hit effects are transfered to the Gargantuan. Blizzard has never released official information about the proc rate of the zombie dogs, but the patch notes for 1.0.4 specifically included nerfs to the proc rate for Burning Dogs and Rabid Dogs. I believe this only refers to their special abilities, however, not their basic attacks.

There is no information on whether the zombie dogs' basic attacks proc on-hit effects or not. I will try to pay attention to this next time I'm using my WD to see whether there is any proc at all for zombie dogs.

Either way, it's not really feasible to rely on attacks from your pets to proc enough life on hit to regenerate health for you.

Fierce Loyalty only effects exactly what it says in its tooltip, which is life regeneration and thorns. No other sources of healing are transferred.

Comment: I thought proc coefficient means how likely it is to trigger an on hit effect, not what % gets transfered to it

Comment: I was not expecting the dogs to heal me with life on hit, but rather to heal themselves. I'm trying to find an optimal build for my pets and me to stay alive. I'm counting on my personal hits to heal me with LOH rather than on my pets. As my stuff does not have Life regeneration, I wont take Fierce Loyalty. One additional question : should I use `Leeching Beasts` rune as a survival skill for my pets ? It states it heals them and me equally, but it has almost no effect on my life regeneration. Consequently, I wonder if it is really effective or not...

Comment: @yx. That's true for all other effects, but LoH gets scaled.

Comment: @Wis That's really personal preference. I use burning dogs. The rune for zombie dogs largely makes little difference in my experience.

Comment: Don't use leeching beasts, as they are bugged in inferno, and go down within 3-4 hits. Better off using fire or poision.

Answer (score 1):

Proc coefficient effects both % gained on attack and % reduction of chance of proc cc's. (I'm unclear if this is also true for critical chance and bleed chance).

I do know that rain of todd for example has a proc coefficient of .5 - and also hits 4x over its 2 second duration. Every hit has a 50% reduction to procs, therefore if you have say 20% fear on echoing fury, each of the 4 hits from RoT will have a 10% chance to fear. as far as LoH goes, proc coefficient is a straight % reduction. So if you had 100 LoH and use RoT, each of the 4 hits will heal 50 life.

Also, RoT is stackable, which means with say an atk speed of 2 per second, you could cast 4 RoT in the same location for 4 hits a second at a .5 proc coefficient. (using the previous example, that's 40% fear chance every half second, and 200 loh every half second, per enemy in the radius of RoT)

Comment: good explanation. I wonder if there is a place where all proc coefficients are listed and up-to-date (cause it changes every two weeks...). I'm currently using the Poison dart with the fire rune and am considering a change for RoT. I'll make some tests to evaluate dps and life leech difference between these two skills.